# Layer post title on top of image Wordpress featured thumbnail image

Tags: css, post-thumbnails, html5

I'm currently trying to layer a post title on top of the posts featured image but all I see at the moment is "**);">**" instead of the image.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<div style="width:609px;height:364px;background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>);"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
```

And here is the CSS for the H2 style

```
article h2 a{
background-color:#bf0c08;
color:#fff;
width:auto;
font-size:30px;
text-decoration:none;
padding:8px;
max-width:479px;
line-height:60px;}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Also a solution would be awesome :)

You can see this on www.ridermagazine.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()` does not return the path of your image. Instead, it returns the complete HTML markup for that image.

You can use this instead:

`$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); echo $image[0];`

If you want a specific size you can pass an additional parameter:

`$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); echo $image[0];`

You can either use a keyword for the size (`thumbnail`, `medium`, `large` or `full`), a size you defined with `add_image_size`, or pass an array with your desired size like so: `array( 100, 200 )`

Comment: That's sorta worked, it's tiled the thumbnail instead of inserting the full size image, check www.ridermagazine.co.uk to see what I mean. Cheers.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the size parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) will echo the entire image tag. You can see it in the source of your site:

`<div style="width:609px;height:364px;background-image:url(<img width=" 609"="" height="364" src="http://ridermagazine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/featuretest.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="featuretest" title="featuretest">);"&gt;<h2><a href="http://ridermagazine.co.uk/?p=1">‘Gill’ promotes underage driving to young motorcycle enthusiast</a></h2></div>`

You need the URL only. Use [get_attachment_thumb_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url) instead. It doesn't echo so modify your code to do that-- `url(ID); ?>);